# How to get jupyter notebook port inside the notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Some applications (e.g. Bokeh) need to know the port of an application in order to work correctly. I can start a jupyter notebook with a default port, but sometimes jupyter takes a different port e.g. when the port is already in use. Therefore, I would like to get the port from inside the notebook and start my code with it, so that it runs independently. I found this snippet that does what I need, but not in every context:

```
%%javascript
IPython.OutputArea.prototype._should_scroll = function(lines) {return false;}
var nb = Jupyter.notebook;
var port = window.location.port;
nb.kernel.execute("PORT = '" + port + "'");
```

Together with the jupyter extension `AppMode` this code does not work anymore. Therefore, I am looking for other, more robust methods of getting the port (and URL) from inside a notebook running a python 3 kernel.

Comment: Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Answer (score 0):

```
from notebook import notebookapp
port_list = [note["port"] for note in notebookapp.list_running_servers()]
```

This returns a list containing all the ports of running jupyter servers

Comment: How do I found out which port belongs to the current notebook?